# How to access the bundle when using Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have a framework that supports `CocaPods`. I have now added support for *Swift Package Manager* but experiencing a crash when trying to access the framework's bundle.

```swift
    static func debuggerBundle(from target: AnyClass) -> Bundle {
        let podBundle = Bundle(for:  target)
        guard let bundleURL = podBundle.url(forResource: "Harlow", withExtension: "bundle"),
        let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL) else { fatalError("Must have a local bundle") }
        return bundle
    }
```

When installing with `CocoaPods`, the `.ipa` contains a `/Frameworks` folder with all the frameworks. But when running with *SPM*, the frameworks do not exist.

*Using CocoaPods*

[image: Using CocoaPods]

*Using SPM*

[image: Using SPM]

**How do we access the framework's bundle with SPM?**

https://github.com/stanwood/Harlow/

Comment: See [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-add-resources-in-swift-package-manager-c437d44ec593). You should declare what resources to `.copy` in your package.swift, and then a `Bundle.module` will be generated for you.

Comment: @Sweeper what about `swift-tools-version 5.1` ? Looks like the Resources are supported from 5.3 only

Comment: Yes that's right. I don't know what you should do for 5.1, except that you should probably update soon :)

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in the comments, SPM package version 5.3 is the minimum for supporting bundle resources. If you need to maintain support for 5.1, you can add a second package file that includes support for 5.3: `Package@swift-5.3.swift`.

Using your Harlow repo as a base, the new Package file will look like this:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Harlow",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v10)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "Harlow",
            targets: ["Harlow"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/shu223/Pulsator.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "0.6.3")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/schmidyy/Loaf.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "0.7.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/stanwood/SourceModel_iOS.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.3.3"))
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Harlow",
            dependencies: ["Pulsator", "SourceModel", "Loaf"],
            resources: [.copy("Resources")]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "HarlowTests",
            dependencies: ["Harlow"]),
    ],
    swiftLanguageVersions: [.v5]
)
```

This will make the `Bundle.module` reference become available. You could provide a static reference to this instance available through your `Bundle` extension like this:

```swift
extension Bundle {
    public static var harlow: Bundle = .module
}
```

With that in place, you should be able to use the `harlow` bundle reference to load your `DefaultSettings.plist`. (`Bundle.harlow.url(forResource:withExtension:)`)