# SwiftUI: Unable to access colors from Common framework's Assets

Tags: ios, swiftui, colors, frameworks, assets

I have a common framework shared by multiple applications. In my common framework, I have colors defined in assets. I use following code to access the colors within common framework.

```
public struct ColorTheme {
    public static let primaryColor = Color("primaryColor")
    public static let secondaryColor = Color("secondaryColor")
    public static let captionColor = Color("captionColor")
}
```

It works fine within the common framework. But as soon as I use the framework in my ZYZ app with syntax `ColorTheme.primaryColor` colors are not loaded and I get following error
`No color named 'primaryColor' found in asset catalog for main bundle`

I know that colors are not in main bundle, but in common framework's bundle. Do you know how should we fix the issue, so we can acess those colors from common frameworks bundle using SwiftUI code?

Comment: have you tried adding `public` to the `static` of your framework?

Comment: Yes, added public. But the error is same, as colors are in different bundle. (Not main),

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the bundle when using Swift Package Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951627/how-to-access-the-bundle-when-using-swift-package-manager)

Answer (score 1):

Following code worked for me. As `Color` do not provides any initializer that accepts bundle, so we have to get `UIColor` first and then convert it to `Color`

```
public extension Bundle {
    static var commonBundle: Bundle {
        return Bundle(identifier: "com.mydomain.common")!
    }
}
extension Color {
    init(_ name: String, bundle: Bundle) {
        self.init(UIColor(named: name, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)!)
    }
}
```

After above extensions I updated my `ColorTheme` as follows

```
public struct ColorTheme {
    public static let primaryColor = Color("primaryColor", bundle: Bundle.commonBundle)
    public static let secondaryColor = Color("secondaryColor", bundle: Bundle.commonBundle)
    public static let captionColor = Color("captionColor", bundle: Bundle.commonBundle)
}
```